# Laravel set an Automatic WHERE Clause

Tags: php, where-clause, laravel, eloquent

I use models that extend a generic_model, which in turn extends Eloquent (so that I have several crud methods I use already set to be inherited).

A lot of the tables I use invoke soft delete, which needs a WHERE clause of...

```
WHERE deleted = 0
```

Is there a way to make Laravel behave in such a way that this WHERE clause is automatically included in all queries and all queries to objects that are related to one another?

e.g.

```
pages where id = 5 and deleted = 0
```

and then...

```
images where page_id = 5 and deleted = 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you're using laravel 3 this is what you needs

on your model

```
public function query()
{

    $query = parent::query();

    $query->where('deleted','=','0');

    return $query;
}
```

if you're using laravel 4 just change the method query for **newQuery**

```
public function newQuery()
{

    $query = parent::newQuery();

    $query->where('deleted','=','0');

    return $query;
}
```

[reference](http://usman.it/filter-eloquent-results-overriding-laravel/)

Comment: Hi, newQuery doesn't work for Laravel 4, do you have an idea of how to do this in Laravel 4 ?

Comment: I've revised it to support Laravel 4

Answer (score 1):

In relationships you can add the where_clause in your return:

```
 public function pages()
{
    return $this->has_many('Page')->where_deleted(0);
}
```

In your Model, you could add something like:

```
public static function active()
{
    return self::where_delete(0)->get();
}
```

to use `Page::active()` instead of `Page::all()`
(Or you can remove the `->get()` from the function in the model, so you can still further modify your query (`Page::active()->order_by('name')`)