# Add WHERE condition to all SQL requests in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm creating an online tool for companies that each have a set of users in Laravel.

When a user is connected, he has a `$connected_company_id` variable

- For every SELECT request (called by ::all(), find(), ...), i would like to add the condition: `where company_id = $connected_company_id`. I have found this post: [laravel set an automatic where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271812/laravel-set-an-automatic-where-clause), but it doesn't work by overriding newQuery().
- For every INSERT request, i would like to add the company_id.

Is this possible **without changing my code inside all the controllers** ?

I thought about extending Eloquent with `customEloquent`, and then make my models extend `customEloquent`, but I don't know how to write the code for customEloquent and if it could work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could make use of the Eloquent Model Events. I assume you have the connected_company_id stored in the Session `company_id`

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent{

   public static function boot(){
         parent::boot();
         //Column to inject when inserting
         static::creating(function ($obj){
             $obj->company_id = Session::get('company_id');
         });

         //Column to inject when updating
         static::updating(function ($obj){
             $obj->company_id = Session::get('company_id');
         });
   }
}
```

You can extend the BaseModel class on all the models that you want the company_id to be inserted or updated. Take a look at [Eloquent Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events) for more information.

The above code will automatically insert or update the company_id to the model that you extend the `BaseModel` to. When you do a `Model::all()` or `Model::get()`, you automatically get the company_id on that Model and you can also perform searches as you requested on Point `

Hope this helps.

Comment: Model::all() and Model::get() doesn't filter through the models that have `company_id==Session::get('company_id')` here.

Comment: for the first bullet point, I have found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271812/laravel-set-an-automatic-where-clause, But it doesn't seem to work on Laravel 4 (even newQuery())

Comment: So you want to have that filter done automatically is it. Because from your pointer I see that you wanted to add the condition every where.

Comment: Yep I want that filter to be done automatically on all `BaseModel` classes.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can just add the company id to the find query. 
`Model::where("company_id","=",$company_id):`
Or you can create a scope:

```
class theModel extends Eloquent {
    static $company_id;
    static for_company($company_id){
           self::company_id=$company_id;
           return __CLASS__;

    }

    public function scopeCompany($query)
    {
        return $query->where('company_id', '=', self::company_id);
    }

}
//And later
$scope=theModel::for_company($company_id);
$res=$scope::company->where(...);
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this. Just a solution I constructed. Let me know if this works. This will not work under PHP 5.3

Comment: I knew about query scopes, actually I would like to have this scope everytime I use the given model, without having to specify the scope. For example theModel::all should already give only those models that have the company_id.  Other point: this is for SELECT requests, howewer, this doesn't add company_id on a save() (cf second bullet point)